# How do I get the center of the screen in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How do I get the world space coordinate of point that is in the center of the screen, in Cocos2d-iPhone?

Answer (score 9):

Simple, just take the height and width and divide it by 2

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CGPoint point = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
```

Here is a somewhat more advanced way to do it.
This will also work if you have called setPosition on the parent of the sprite (=self in this example)

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCSprite* centerSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"sprite"];
CGPoint centerPoint = ccpSub(ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2), [self position]);
[centerSprite setPosition:centerPoint];
[self addChild: centerSprite];
```

Comment: That doesn't give the center of the screen. That gives half the screen size.

Comment: (0, 0) is relative to its parent, not the bottom left corner of the screen. It won't work if the parent moved.

Comment: this code isn't looking at the parent but at the Cocos Director as a whole and the window size of the entire Cocos. If your Cocos view indeed spans the entire screen, then this code will give you the exact center point.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now it should also work when the parent is moved

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exact center of the screen no matter what framework you are using, Cocos or not, and also even if Cocos is not set to use the entire screen (such is the case sometimes if you crop Cocos to make room for ads) by doing something like this:

```
int width=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
int height=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height
CGPoint center=ccp(width/2,height/2);
```

Note the `ccp` macro works in Cocos only; otherwise, use `CGPointMake`